# Haskell. Two lists of the same length are given. Write a "diff" function that builds the difference as follows

Tags: haskell

Two lists of the same length are given. Write a diff function that builds the difference as follows.

Example:

```
 diff [1,2,3,0] [1,3,4,0] -> [Same, Different 2 3, Different 3 4, Same]
 diff [0,0,0,0,0] [0,0,1,0,2] -> [Same, Same, Different 0 1, Same, Different 0 2]
```

It is also necessary to implement the data type required for the task.

I tried to solve this problem as follows:

```
data MyData3 = Same | Different Int Int deriving(Show)

diff (h:t)(h1:t1) = if (h == h1) then Same : diff t t1 else Different h h1 : diff t t1
diff [] = []
```

But the program is interrupted by an error: Equations for ‘diff’ have different numbers of arguments. Please help me solve this problem and fix the code.

Comment: that's a very good start, you've just got a little bit of tidying up to do. The error message is actually perfectly clear here - what do you think it means?

Comment: (PS I don't know if you're not allowed to use certain library functions, but [ZipWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith), from the Prelude, is the easiest way to implement this. Still, as you've shown, it's not hard to write this function without it.)

Comment: Thanks for your question, it helped to comprehend the task and see the error)

Comment: either `data MyData3 = Same Int | Different Int Int`, or `data MyData3 = Same | Difference Int` would make more sense, no?

Comment: Yes  Will Ness , you are right)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right.
However, the function you wrote need to be fixed.

Assuming that the length of the list on the arguments will be always the same.
We take two arguments so we write the function's type signature:

```hs
diff :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [MyData3]
```

Then, we identify the base case which is when the list is empty.

```hs
diff [] [] = []
```

Lastly, we write the complete function like below.
I used guards here.

```hs
diff (h1:t1) (h2:t2)
  | h1 == h2  = Same : diff t1 t2
  | otherwise = Different h1 h2 : diff t1 t2
```

Hence, the complete code is like this.

```hs
data MyData3 = Same | Different Int Int deriving (Show)

diff :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [MyData3]
diff [] [] = []
diff (h1:t1) (h2:t2)
  | h1 == h2  = Same : diff t1 t2
  | otherwise = Different h1 h2 : diff t1 t2
```

Now, we write the main function.

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ diff [1,2,3,0] [1,3,4,0]
  print $ diff [0,0,0,0,0] [0,0,1,0,2]
```

Compile and run the code.
We will get:

```
[Same,Different 2 3,Different 3 4,Same]
[Same,Same,Different 0 1,Same,Different 0 2]
```

Okay.
The code run just as expected.
Please learn more about list and how to write a function in Haskell.
Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're writing this function in a way that will crash when given two lists of different length, when it's so simple to make it cover all input correctly. (You don't actually need more than 2 patterns in total.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have said it. "Assuming that the length of the list on the arguments will be always the same." Yes, we could have use `if` instead.

Comment: I know you stated, but it seems strange to make this assumption when the resulting code is no simpler. (And I wasn't talking about `if` vs guards at all, that's just stylistic preference here.)

Comment: Thank Wisn !! You helped me a lot, a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is because your second clause only has one parameter. Indeed:

```
diff :: Int -> Int -> [MyData3]
diff (h:t) (h1:t1) = …
diff [] = …
```

We thus can fix this, by adding an extra empty list:

```
diff :: Int -> Int -> [MyData3]
diff (h:t) (h1:t1) = …
diff [] [] = …
```

That being said, the function is still not very "safe". Indeed, imagine that someone will pass `diff [1] [2,3]`, then the function will raise an error, since the tw lists have a different length.

We can solve this problem in multiple ways. We can for example stop the processing, from the moment, one of the list is exhausted, we can implement this for example with `zipWith`:

```
diff :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [MyData3]
diff = zipWith f
    where f x y | x == y = Same
                | otherwise = Different x y
```

Or we can return a `Maybe [MyData3]` that is `Nothing` if the length of the two lists differ, and `Just …` if these are the same.

Comment: My preferred solution, apart from `zipWith`, is to simply have a second pattern of `diff _ _ = []`, which (because of the content of the first pattern) must match any input where either list is empty.

Comment: Thank Willem Van Onsem and Robin Zigmond !! Right !!! I would have been looking for this error for a long time) A beautiful solution with zipWith I will take note of it.